# Android layout_centerHorizontal

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi guys while I was designing an app, I got to wonder why in ScrollView you cannot go `layout_centerHorizontal = "true"` in android. So below is my simple code I wrote for this purpose. The first button does not feature `layout_centerHorizontal = "true"` although I wrote it there manually, it doesn't align in the center.

However, the second button which is outside `ScrollView` it aligns perfectly in the middle of the width of the parent.

Why is this?

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A Scrollview is not a RelativeLayout, it is a FrameLayout. I believe that attribute only works on children of RelativeLayouts. I think you have to use gravity to center in a Scrollview

Comment: ScrollView extends FrameLayout so you would need to use    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal".  It is also suggested to use a parent layout within the scrollview if you have more than one child.

Comment: ahh okay that's great thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this -

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please share why this would solve the problem, rather than just pasting the code

Comment: A Scrollview is not a RelativeLayout. Its not extending the properties of Relative Layout

Comment: Thanks. Please make a habit of including that in your future answers.

Comment: From the comments above, we explained that. What the comment here is asking for clarification on your code-only answer. You need to explain that setting the gravity in a Scrollview will affect all the elements within it

Answer (score 1):

A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.

Moreover, as a child of ScrollView means of FrameLayout, you cannot use

```
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

If you want to make button in center please use

```
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```